# Docker: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm really new to Docker. I'm trying to run Wordpress, and I've run into an error.

```
$ docker-compose up -d
testpublichtml_mariadb_1 is up-to-date
Starting 00b4dc8e3264_testpublichtml_wordpress_1

ERROR: for wordpress  Cannot start service wordpress: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint 
00b4dc8e3264_testpublichtml_wordpress_1 (63165c221c0b2b11d513e97d35afa39146790086115029b9bb229212d0c8c06a): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
$
```

My guess is to try and check if something is on port 80, though I'm not sure how to check that.

When I enter `netstat -tulnp | grep ':80'`, I get:

```
$ netstat -tulnp | grep ':80'
netstat: option requires an argument -- p
Usage:  netstat [-AaLlnW] [-f address_family | -p protocol]
netstat [-gilns] [-f address_family]
netstat -i | -I interface [-w wait] [-abdgRtS]
netstat -s [-s] [-f address_family | -p protocol] [-w wait]
netstat -i | -I interface -s [-f address_family | -p protocol]
netstat -m [-m]
netstat -r [-Aaln] [-f address_family]
netstat -rs [-s]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have some service running on port 80. To check this, execute the following command.

`netstat -tulnp | grep ':80'`

The last column is PID/Program name of your process. If you want to kill it, use the following command.

`kill PID`

After that, you should be able to start your container.

Comment: When I enter `kill PID`, I get `-bash: kill: PID: arguments must be process or job IDs`

Comment: You don't have to put the word PID. PID word must be substituted for the value of the last column of the output of `netstat -tulnp | grep ':80'`. Please, validate the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "last column". I have added in my question the message I get when I enter this command.

Comment: Which distro are you using? Make sure that you're executing the command as root.